# Customise AddForm.aspx from a List

Tags: list, custom-list, list-form

I need to customise the AddForm.aspx for a list so that when the user clic the save button, the system creates 4 items in the same list with some parameters I can create in a form there.

The only way I can think of is with a WebPart, but I wonder if there's any way of doing this without the creation of the Webpart.

Maybe with designer or something like that.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a web part and use it on a page or you can use a SharePoint Form Generator like InfoPath, or Nintex Forms, or something like that

Comment: Thanks, I know how to create a Webpart. So I will go with this solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach SharePoint designer workflow on the item created.
On creation of new item (i.e. click of save), Create new Item in same list using SharePoint designer.

Also you can add java script on your new form, PreSave() which executes when the save button is clicked. In PreSave() you can write client script code to create new item in the list.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I think I'm going to use the Wep Part Solution.